# Screen from private route in react wont render but every other screen does

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My screen from Private Route in react won't render but every other screen does, I use the private route to render my PrivateScreen.js , everything looks correct but I just don't get it.

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

//Routing
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';

//Screens
import PrivateScreen from './components/screens/PrivateScreen'
import LoginScreen from './components/screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from './components/screens/RegisterScreen'
import ForgotPasswordScreen from './components/screens/ForgotPasswordScreen'
import ResetPasswordScreen from './components/screens/ResetPasswordScreen'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="app">
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute element={<PrivateScreen />}/>}/>
                <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterScreen />} />
                <Route path="/forgotpassword" element={<ForgotPasswordScreen />} />
                <Route path="/passwordreset/:resetToken" element={< ResetPasswordScreen />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Navigate, Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = () => {
    const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("authToken");

    return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**PrivateScreen.js**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import './PrivateScreen.css';


const PrivateScreen = () =>{

    console.log("PrivateScreen is rendered");

    const history = useNavigate();

    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [privateData, setPrivateData] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!localStorage.getItem("authToken")){
            history("/login");
        }

        const fetchPrivateData = async () => {

            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`
                }
            }

            try {
                const {data} = await axios.get("/api/private", config);
                setPrivateData(data.data);
            }catch (e) {
                localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
                setError("You are not authorized, please login");
            }
        }

        fetchPrivateData().then().catch(error => {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        });
    }, [history]);

    const logoutHandler = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
        history("/login");
    }

    return (
        <div className={`email-verification-screen ${error ? "error" : ""}`}>
            {error ? (
                <span className="error-message">{error}</span>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className="email-verification-screen__content">
                        {privateData}
                    </div>
                    <h1>SFSFSFSFSF</h1>
                    <button
                        onClick={logoutHandler}
                        className="email-verification-screen__logout-button"
                    >
                        Logout
                    </button>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export  default PrivateScreen;
```

I tried logging every screen and the PrivateScreen is the only one that isn't being logged, i tried with ChatGPT and searched the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wrap your sub routes inside main route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1AqZ.png)

To render the Outlet of react-router-dom you need to wrap your sub routes inside the PrivetRoute component.

This above solution will render your private screen successfully.

Comment: <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<PrivateScreen />}/>
  </Route>

Comment: your welcome, if you have others doubts you can ask me here only.